# MySQL Foreign key constraint are incompatible

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

MySQL Version 8.0.17

The full error reads:

> Referencing column 'groupLineId' and referenced column 'groupLineId' in foreign key constraint 'salesItemLine-groupLine' are incompatible

I am trying to link two tables via the groupLineId which are both NOT NULL VARCHAR(12).  I am not sure why I am getting the error. I have several other foreign key relationships like this in my DB.

I am using the following code to generate the two tables. (Note: code for invoice table not shown)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reports`.`groupLine` (
  `groupLineId` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
  `lineNum` INT NOT NULL,
  `invoiceId` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`groupLineId`, `lineNum`, `invoiceId`),
  INDEX `groupLine-invoice_idx` (`invoiceId` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `groupLine-invoice`
    FOREIGN KEY (`invoiceId`)
    REFERENCES `reports`.`invoice` (`invoiceId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reports`.`salesItemLine` (
  `groupLineId` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
  `lineNum` INT NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(256) NULL,
  `amount` DECIMAL NULL,
  `detailType` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`groupLineId`, `lineNum`),
  INDEX `salesItemLine-groupLine_idx` (`groupLineId` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `salesItemLine-groupLine`
    FOREIGN KEY (`groupLineId`)
    REFERENCES `reports`.`groupLine` (`groupLineId`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: I tested on an instance of 8.0.18 and there was no error. I suggest the error is due to something you have not shown in this question. What are the collations of each table? `select table_name, table_collation from information_schema.tables where table_schema='reports';`

Comment: Hey Bill, all table collations are set to utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci.

Comment: Well, I could not reproduce an error when I tested the tables you show. Either the error comes from some different table, or a different MySQL instance, or there's a significant difference between 8.0.17 and 8.0.18.

Comment: You you were right it wasn't a code problem. It was how I was making changes and using the Forward Engineer feature of MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Okay, I'm glad you found the problem. I have voted to close this question as "can no longer be reproduced."

Comment: Sound good I posted a detailed answer of why it was occuring.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone comes across this my problem was how I was making changes and using the "Forward Engineer" feature of MySQL Workbench. I had originally created the database with groupLineId ID as type INT. I then changed the model to make the groupLineId in both tables to VARCHAR(12). Then when I would run "Forward Engineer" it would first write the new groupLine table and change the type of groupLineId to VARCHAR(12) this would then break the existing FROGIEN key with salesItemLine table which has not been updated and still has the type of groupeLineId as INT.

The solution was to DROP both tables before rerunning the forward engineering. (Or at least manually dropping the existing constraints)

Comment: Just a note. Be wary of all the tools that help you design databases. Some are good, sone aren't. When push comes to shove, check the resulting SQL the tools produce. That's where the truth is.